# Find the intervals of increase and decrease of the function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

Tags: functions, inequality, polynomials

Find the intervals of increase and decrease of the function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.

The problem is from the book "Problems in Calculus of One Variable" by I.A Maron. The solution given in the book is as follows:

> Isolating the perfect square from the square trinomial , we have $f(x)=a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+\frac {4ac-b^2}{4a}$. If $a>0$ then the function $f(x)$ will increase at those values of $x$ satisfying the inequality $x+\frac {b}{2a}>0$ i.e $x>-\frac {b}{2a}$ and decrease when $x+\frac {b}{2a}<0$ i.e $x<-\frac {b}{2a}$. Thus if $a>0$  the function $f(x)$ decreases in the interval $(-\infty, -\frac {b}{2a})$ and increases in the interval $(-\frac {b}{2a},\infty)$; at $x=-\frac {b}{2a}$ the function $f(x)$ takes the minimum value $\frac {4ac-b^2}{4a}$.Similarly, if $a<0$  the function $f(x)$ increases in the interval $(-\infty, -\frac {b}{2a})$ and decreases in the interval $(-\frac {b}{2a},\infty)$; at $x=-\frac {b}{2a}$ the function $f(x)$ takes the maximum value $\frac {4ac-b^2}{4a}$.

However, I am not getting how are they saying in case $a>0$ that $f(x)$ decreases in the interval $(-\infty, -\frac {b}{2a})$ and increases in the interval $(-\frac {b}{2a},\infty)$ . Same goes for the case,  $a<0$. I mean how are they concluding it ? I need an explanation of this without using calculus ...I am not quite getting it...Maybe there are similar threads in this site concerning the same topic  but I can't seem to find it either...

Comment: I suggest you make a drawing of a parabola.

Comment: Are $~\color{red}{\text{derivatives}}~$ off limits?  If not, then it seems like your posting is overkill when compared with $$f'(x) = 2ax + b.$$  The function is decreasing when the derivative is negative and increasing when the derivative is positive.

Comment: @M.Wind Yeah , if we make a drawing of the parabola , it becomes very much evident but is there a way to see it algebraically or through inequalities ....

Comment: Let $x$ increase. Let $Q=x+(b/(2a))$. Then $Q$ also increases. If $Q<0$ and $Q$ increases, then $Q^2$ decreases; if $Q>0$ and $Q$ increases then $Q^2$ increases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can observe that, if $a>0$ then we have:

$$\begin{align}f(x)=\underbrace{a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2}_{\geq 0}+\underbrace{\frac {4ac-b^2}{4a}}_{\text {constant term}}&\ge \frac {4ac-b^2}{4a}\end{align}$$

This implies that, if $x_2>x_1\geq-\frac {b}{2a}$, then: $$\begin{align}&x_2+\frac {b}{2a}>x_1+\frac {b}{2a}\ge 0\\
\implies &\left(x_2+\frac {b}{2a}\right)^2>\left(x_1+\frac {b}{2a}\right)^2\\
\implies &f(x_2)>f(x_1)\end{align}$$

Similarly, if $a<0$ we have:

$$\begin{align}f(x)=\underbrace{a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2}_{\leq 0}+\underbrace{\frac {4ac-b^2}{4a}}_{\text {constant term}}&\leq \frac {4ac-b^2}{4a}\end{align}$$

and note that if $-\frac {b}{2a}\leq x_2<x_1$, then you get:

$$\begin{align}&0\leq x_2+\frac {b}{2a}<x_1+\frac {b}{2a}\\
\implies &\left(x_2+\frac {b}{2a}\right)^2< \left(x_1+\frac {b}{2a}\right)^2\\
\implies &f(x_2)<f(x_1).\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=0$, $b\neq0$, and $x_1>x_2$.

Thus, $f(x_1)-f(x_2)=bx_1-bx_2=b(x_1-x_2)$ and we see that $f$ increases on $\mathbb R$ for $b>0$ and decreases on $\mathbb R$ for $b<0$.

Also in this case, if $b=0$ so $f$ is a constant.

Let $a>0$ , $\{x_1,x_2\}\subset\left[-\frac{b}{2a},+\infty\right)$ and $x_1>x_2$ again.

Thus, $$f(x_1)-f(x_2)=ax_1^2+bx_1+c-(ax_2^2+bx_2+c)=(x_1-x_2)(a(x_1+x_2)+b)>$$
$$>(x_1-x_2)\left(a\left(-\frac{b}{2a}-\frac{b}{2a}\right)+b\right)=0,$$
which says that $f$ increases on $\left[-\frac{b}{2a},+\infty\right)$

Let $a>0$,$\{x_1,x_2\}\subset\left(-\infty,-\frac{b}{2a}\right]$ and $x_1>x_2.$

Thus, $$f(x_1)-f(x_2)=ax_1^2+bx_1+c-(ax_2^2+bx_2+c)=(x_1-x_2)(a(x_1+x_2)+b)<$$
$$<(x_1-x_2)\left(a\left(-\frac{b}{2a}-\frac{b}{2a}\right)+b\right)=0,$$
which says that $f$ decreases on $\left(-\infty,-\frac{b}{2a}\right].$

Since $$\left(-\infty,-\frac{b}{2a}\right]\cup\left[-\frac{b}{2a},+\infty\right)=\mathbb R,$$ we are done in this case.

We can end a work for $a<0$ similarly.